# How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class

Tags: php, soap

I'm used to writing PHP code, but do not often use Object-Oriented coding. I now need to interact with SOAP (as a client) and am not able to get the syntax right. I've got a WSDL file which allows me to properly set up a new connection using the SoapClient class. However, I'm unable to actually make the right call and get data returned. I need to send the following (simplified) data:

- Contact ID
- Contact Name
- General Description
- Amount

There are two functions defined in the WSDL document, but I only need one ("FirstFunction" below). Here is the script I run to get information on the available functions and types:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/webservices?wsdl");
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

And here is the output it generates:

```
array(
  [0] => "FirstFunction Function1(FirstFunction $parameters)",
  [1] => "SecondFunction Function2(SecondFunction $parameters)",
);

array(
  [0] => struct Contact {
    id id;
    name name;
  }
  [1] => string "string description"
  [2] => string "int amount"
}
```

Say I want to make a call to the FirstFunction with the data:

- Contact ID: 100
- Contact Name: John
- General Description: Barrel of Oil
- Amount: 500

What would be the right syntax? I've been trying all sorts of options but it appears the soap structure is quite flexible so there are very many ways of doing this. Couldn't figure it out from the manual either...

---

UPDATE 1: tried sample from MMK:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/webservices?wsdl");

$params = array(
  "id" => 100,
  "name" => "John",
  "description" => "Barrel of Oil",
  "amount" => 500,
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("Function1", array($params));
```

But I get this response: `Object has no 'Contact' property`. As you can see in the output of `getTypes()`, there is a `struct` called `Contact`, so I guess I somehow need to make clear my parameters include the Contact data, but the question is: how?

UPDATE 2: I've also tried these structures, same error.

```
$params = array(
  array(
    "id" => 100,
    "name" => "John",
  ),
  "Barrel of Oil",
  500,
);
```

As well as:

```
$params = array(
  "Contact" => array(
    "id" => 100,
    "name" => "John",
  ),
  "description" => "Barrel of Oil",
  "amount" => 500,
);
```

Error in both cases: Object has no 'Contact' property`

Answer (score 190):

### This is what you need to do.

I tried to recreate the situation...

---

- For this example, I created a .NET sample WebService (WS) with a `WebMethod` called `Function1` expecting the following params:

> Function1(Contact Contact, string description, int amount)

- Where `Contact` is just a model that has getters and setters for `id` and `name` like in your case.
- You can download the .NET sample WS at:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pz1w94a52o5xah/11593623.zip

---

### The code.

This is what you need to do at PHP side:

*(Tested and working)*

```
<?php
// Create Contact class
class Contact {
    public function __construct($id, $name) 
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

// Initialize WS with the WSDL
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:10139/Service1.asmx?wsdl");

// Create Contact obj
$contact = new Contact(100, "John");

// Set request params
$params = array(
  "Contact" => $contact,
  "description" => "Barrel of Oil",
  "amount" => 500,
);

// Invoke WS method (Function1) with the request params 
$response = $client->__soapCall("Function1", array($params));

// Print WS response
var_dump($response);

?>
```

---

### Testing the whole thing.

- If you do `print_r($params)` you will see the following output, as your WS would expect:

> Array ( [Contact] => Contact Object ( [id] => 100 [name] => John )
> [description] => Barrel of Oil [amount] => 500 )

- When I debugged the .NET sample WS I got the following:

[image]

*(As you can see, `Contact` object is not `null` nor the other params. That means your request was successfully done from PHP side)*

- The response from the .NET sample WS was the expected one and this is what I got at PHP side:

> object(stdClass)[3]   public 'Function1Result' => string 'Detailed
> information of your request! id: 100, name: John, description: Barrel
> of Oil, amount: 500' (length=98)

---

Comment: Perfect! I acted like I knew a little bit more about SOAP services than I really did and this got me where I needed to be.

Comment: I didn't ask the question, otherwise I would have. The question and this answer got an upvote from me though.

Comment: @user should accept it :)
BTW, very nice answer, complete and very clear. +1

Comment: Thanks for this! Lil' boost to understand SOAP structure.

Answer (score 83):

You can use SOAP services this way too:

```
<?php 
//Create the client object
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL');

//Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in 
//the associative array
$params = array('CountryName' => 'Spain', 'CityName' => 'Alicante');
$response = $soapclient->getWeather($params);

var_dump($response);

// Get the Cities By Country
$param = array('CountryName' => 'Spain');
$response = $soapclient->getCitiesByCountry($param);

var_dump($response);
```

This is an example with a real service, and it works when the url is up.

**Just in case the http://www.webservicex.net is down.**

Here is another example **using the example web service** from [W3C XML Web Services](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_services.asp) example, you can find more information on the link.

```
<?php
//Create the client object
$soapclient = new SoapClient('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL');

//Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in
//the associative array
$params = array('Celsius' => '25');
$response = $soapclient->CelsiusToFahrenheit($params);

var_dump($response);

// Get the Celsius degrees from the Farenheit
$param = array('Fahrenheit' => '25');
$response = $soapclient->FahrenheitToCelsius($param);

var_dump($response);
```

This is working and returning the converted temperature values.

Comment: I get the following error : object(stdClass)#70 (1) { ["GetWeatherResult"]=> string(14) "Data Not Found" } Any idea?

Comment: Seems they have changed the strings of the cities. 
I've just updated the example with another call to another service they provide and it's working.
I tried to use the strings they return as cities, but does not seem to work fine, anyways the getCitiesByCountry() function serves as example on how to make a call.

Comment: This example is down again

Comment: @CSchwarz thanks for the feedback updated the answer with a different web service extracted from W3C page. Almost all web services now they need api key to consume them, I think it's a bit excesive for a quick example.

Answer (score 32):

First initialize webservices:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/webservices?wsdl");
```

Then set and pass the parameters:

```
$params = array (
    "arg0" => $contactid,
    "arg1" => $desc,
    "arg2" => $contactname
);

$response = $client->__soapCall('methodname', array($params));
```

Note that the method name is available in WSDL as operation name, e.g.:

```
<operation name="methodname">
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this but I get the error "Object has no 'Contact' property". Will update my question with full details. Any ideas?

Comment: @user16441 Can you post the WSDL and schema of the service?  I usually start by figuring out what XML the service expects, then using WireShark to figure out what my client is actually sending.

Answer (score 24):

I don't know why my web service has the same structure with you but it doesn't need Class for parameter, just is array.

For example: 
 - My WSDL:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:ns="http://www.kiala.com/schemas/psws/1.0">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:createOrder reference="260778">
            <identification>
                <sender>5390a7006cee11e0ae3e0800200c9a66</sender>
                <hash>831f8c1ad25e1dc89cf2d8f23d2af...fa85155f5c67627</hash>
                <originator>VITS-STAELENS</originator>
            </identification>
            <delivery>
                <from country="ES" node=””/>
                <to country="ES" node="0299"/>
            </delivery>
            <parcel>
                <description>Zoethout thee</description>
                <weight>0.100</weight>
                <orderNumber>10K24</orderNumber>
                <orderDate>2012-12-31</orderDate>
            </parcel>
            <receiver>
                <firstName>Gladys</firstName>
                <surname>Roldan de Moras</surname>
                <address>
                    <line1>Calle General Oraá 26</line1>
                    <line2>(4º izda)</line2>
                    <postalCode>28006</postalCode>
                    <city>Madrid</city>
                    <country>ES</country>
                </address>
                <email>gverbruggen@kiala.com</email>
                <language>es</language>
            </receiver>
        </ns:createOrder>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I var_dump:

```
var_dump($client->getFunctions());
var_dump($client->getTypes());
```

Here is result:

```
array
  0 => string 'OrderConfirmation createOrder(OrderRequest $createOrder)' (length=56)

array
  0 => string 'struct OrderRequest {
 Identification identification;
 Delivery delivery;
 Parcel parcel;
 Receiver receiver;
 string reference;
}' (length=130)
  1 => string 'struct Identification {
 string sender;
 string hash;
 string originator;
}' (length=75)
  2 => string 'struct Delivery {
 Node from;
 Node to;
}' (length=41)
  3 => string 'struct Node {
 string country;
 string node;
}' (length=46)
  4 => string 'struct Parcel {
 string description;
 decimal weight;
 string orderNumber;
 date orderDate;
}' (length=93)
  5 => string 'struct Receiver {
 string firstName;
 string surname;
 Address address;
 string email;
 string language;
}' (length=106)
  6 => string 'struct Address {
 string line1;
 string line2;
 string postalCode;
 string city;
 string country;
}' (length=99)
  7 => string 'struct OrderConfirmation {
 string trackingNumber;
 string reference;
}' (length=71)
  8 => string 'struct OrderServiceException {
 string code;
 OrderServiceException faultInfo;
 string message;
}' (length=97)
```

So in my code:

```
    $client  = new SoapClient('http://packandship-ws.kiala.com/psws/order?wsdl');

    $params = array(
        'reference' => $orderId,
        'identification' => array(
            'sender' => param('kiala', 'sender_id'),
            'hash' => hash('sha512', $orderId . param('kiala', 'sender_id') . param('kiala', 'password')),
            'originator' => null,
        ),
        'delivery' => array(
            'from' => array(
                'country' => 'es',
                'node' => '',
            ),
            'to' => array(
                'country' => 'es',
                'node' => '0299'
            ),
        ),
        'parcel' => array(
            'description' => 'Description',
            'weight' => 0.200,
            'orderNumber' => $orderId,
            'orderDate' => date('Y-m-d')
        ),
        'receiver' => array(
            'firstName' => 'Customer First Name',
            'surname' => 'Customer Sur Name',
            'address' => array(
                'line1' => 'Line 1 Adress',
                'line2' => 'Line 2 Adress',
                'postalCode' => 28006,
                'city' => 'Madrid',
                'country' => 'es',
                ),
            'email' => 'test.ceres@yahoo.com',
            'language' => 'es'
        )
    );
    $result = $client->createOrder($params);
    var_dump($result);
```

but it successfully!

Comment: Your example is more helpfull, cause it shows structure dependecies

Answer (score 5):

If you create the object of SoapParam, This will resolve your problem. Create a class and map it with object type given by WebService, Initialize the values and send in the request. See the sample below.

```
struct Contact {

    function Contact ($pid, $pname)
    {
      id = $pid;
      name = $pname;
  }
}

$struct = new Contact(100,"John");

$soapstruct = new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Contact","http://soapinterop.org/xsd");

$ContactParam = new SoapParam($soapstruct, "Contact")

$response = $client->Function1($ContactParam);
```

Answer (score 4):

read this;-

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php

Or

This is a good example, for the SOAP function "__call".
However it is deprecated.

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "http://webservices.tekever.eu/ctt/?wsdl";
    $int_zona = 5;
    $int_peso = 1001;
    $cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl);
    print "<p>Envio Internacional: ";
    $vem = $cliente->__call('CustoEMSInternacional',array($int_zona, $int_peso));
    print $vem;
    print "</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

First, use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) to create your soap project from the wsdl. Try to send a request to play with the wsdl's operations. Observe how the xml request composes your data fields.

And then, if you are having problem getting SoapClient acts as you want, here is how I debug it. Set the option *trace* so that the function *__getLastRequest()* is available for use.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://yourwdsdlurl.com?wsdl', ['trace' => true]);
$params = ['user' => 'Hey', 'account' => '12345'];
$response = $soapClient->__soapCall('<operation>', $params);
$xml = $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
```

Then the *$xml* variable contains the xml that SoapClient compose for your request. Compare this xml with the one generated in the SoapUI.

For me, SoapClient seems to ignore the keys of the associative array *$params* and interpret it as indexed array, causing wrong parameter data in the xml. That is, if I reorder the data in *$params*, the *$response* is completely different:

```
$params = ['account' => '12345', 'user' => 'Hey'];
$response = $soapClient->__soapCall('<operation>', $params);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I just wrapped the arguments like this and it works now.

```
    $args = array();
    $args['Header'] = array(
        'CustomerCode' => 'dsadsad',
        'Language' => 'fdsfasdf'
    );
    $args['RequestObject'] = $whatever;

    // this was the catch, double array with "Request"
    $response = $this->client->__soapCall($name, array(array( 'Request' => $args )));
```

Using this function:

```
 print_r($this->client->__getLastRequest());
```

You can see the Request XML whether it's changing or not depending on your arguments.

Use [ trace = 1, exceptions = 0 ] in SoapClient options.

Answer (score 1):

**getLastRequest():**

This method works only if the SoapClient object was created with the trace option set to TRUE.

TRUE in this case is represented by 1

```
$wsdl = storage_path('app/mywsdl.wsdl');
try{

  $options = array(
               // 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
               'trace'=>1,
               'exceptions'=>1,
               
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
             //   'stream_context' => stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)
        );
           // $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );
        $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
        $client     = new \SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a multi-dimensional array, you can try the following:

```
$params = array(
   array(
      "id" => 100,
      "name" => "John",
   ),
   "Barrel of Oil",
   500
);
```

in PHP an array is a structure and is very flexible. Normally with soap calls I use an XML wrapper so unsure if it will work.

### EDIT:

What you may want to try is creating a json query to send or using that to create a xml buy sort of following what is on this page: http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/08/php-converting-rss-to-json.html

Comment: thanks, but it did not work either. How do you use XML wrappers exactly, perhaps that is easier to use than this...

Comment: First you have to make sure that your WSDL can handle XML wrappers. But it is similar, you build the request in XML and in most cases use curl. I have use SOAP with XML to process transactions through banks. You can check out these as a starter point. http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=424619#post4004636 http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need declare class **Contract**

```
class Contract {
  public $id;
  public $name;
}

$contract = new Contract();
$contract->id = 100;
$contract->name = "John";

$params = array(
  "Contact" => $contract,
  "description" => "Barrel of Oil",
  "amount" => 500,
);
```

or

```
$params = array(
  $contract,
  "description" => "Barrel of Oil",
  "amount" => 500,
);
```

Then

```
$response = $client->__soapCall("Function1", array("FirstFunction" => $params));
```

or

```
$response = $client->__soapCall("Function1", $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to generate php5 objects with WsdlInterpreter class. See more here: https://github.com/gkwelding/WSDLInterpreter

for example:

```
require_once 'WSDLInterpreter-v1.0.0/WSDLInterpreter.php';
$wsdlLocation = '<your wsdl url>?wsdl';
$wsdlInterpreter = new WSDLInterpreter($wsdlLocation);
$wsdlInterpreter->savePHP('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below code might be helpful**

```
    $wsdl ='My_WSDL_Service.wsdl";
    $options = array(
        'login' => 'user-name',
        'password' => 'Password',
    );
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
        $params = array(
            'para1' => $para1,
            'para2' => $para2
        );
        $res = $client->My_WSDL_Service($params);
```