# Soap Error : XML validation error on request: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'Id' must appear on element

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, soap-client

i am requesting the java soap web services from the php program. My code is like follow

```
<?php
 $options = array('features' => 
    SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE + SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
try{
     $sClient = new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.101:8080/person/Person.wsdl');
    //  $sClient = new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.11:8080/DNAHMS/webservice/onlineBooking/Hotel.wsdl',$options);
        //$params = array('Id'=> '1');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($sClient->__getFunctions());
        echo "</pre>";

        $parms  = array("Id"=>1);
        $response = $sClient->__call('getPerson',$parms);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($response);
        echo "</pre>";





    } catch(SoapFault $e){
        echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($e);
        echo "<pre>";
    }
    ?>
```

here i am Person.wsdl when i call directly to browser it has no error and aslo this is valid xml file. 
when i run this i will get soap fault like below :

cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'Id' must appear on element 'ns1:GetPersonRequest'
Any help will appreciate by hearty

Comment: seems having isse with syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this link could help you:

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

[How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)