# Send SMS in magento with external webservice

Tags: xml, magento, soap, sms

I want to use this http://smsalert.no/systorsmsvarious/systorsmsvarious.asmx?op=SendMessageToMobile
to send message from magento after user submit form but I dont know how to call and pass parameters to sms function. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Have a look in to the answers on stack-overflow. Its useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729179/sms-integration-with-magento-api

Comment: I am not sure if you have tried this extension https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

The page tells you that you can use a SOAP-call or an HTTP request with both GET or POST methods. So, you can set up a SoapClient, which requires some additional knowledge.

### Using HTTP GET

The easiest method to send an SMS message seems to be calling this URL with correct GET parameters sMobileNumer, sMessage, sUser and sPass.

```
http://smsalert.no/systorsmsvarious/systorsmsvarious.asmx/SendMessageToMobile?sMobileNumber=string&sMessage=string&sUser=string&sPass=string
```

Calling URLs in PHP can be done with:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

By the way: You should run some tests with special characters if there will be some of them included in sMessage.

### Using SOAP

If you want to use this service through SOAP, you'll get some answers there: [How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

I'm unable to test it because I don't have an account for this service, but the code should be similar to this:

```php
/* Initialize webservice with your WSDL */
$client = new SoapClient("http://smsalert.no/systorsmsvarious/systorsmsvarious.asmx?wsdl");

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
  "sMobileNumber"   => "0123456789",
  "sMessage"        => "Your message",
  "sUser"           => "username",
  "sPass"           => "password"
);

/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: SendMessageToMobile */
$response = $client->__soapCall("SendMessageToMobile", $params);

/* Print webservice response */
var_dump($response);
```

The $response variable will tell you if everything went good, or if there have been some errors.