# Connection using Soap API

Tags: asp.net, sugarcrm

I want to connect my Sugar CRM system with ASP.NEt application using SOAP API. I want to pass only 2 values from sugar CRM system to another application . Only Name and Id . Please tell me how to make connection and pass the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know you went through this thread or not..

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/integrate-sugarcrm-my-asp-net-application-25215/

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code refer to this [How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

'Spain', 'projectid_c' => 'mahima');

    $response = $client->call("createNewProject",($params);

    print_r($response);
    exit();
    }
}

?>