# How to connect to a webservice api php

Tags: php, xml, api, rest

I have a form that is supposed to submit data to an external database, 
using a certain Vehicle_Policy_Push web method, using this webservice link: https://www.niid.org/NIA_API/Service.asmx, but I am lost, I dont have an idea of how to execute this, I have tried to use this with this method:

```
<form name="niid"      id     = "1"
                       action = "https://www.niid.org/NIA_API/Service.asmx"
                       method = "post"
                       >
                       <input name="Username" type   = "text" />

                       <input name=""         type   = "submit"
                                              value  = "Submit" />
</form>
```

but nothing comes up, so I bet am doing a lot of things wrong.

I need guidance on this, is there anyone who has successfully posted to a webservice?

Comment: It is a SOAP-based webinterface. Use a [SOAP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

Comment: The service has to support this type of `POST` request - perhaps you can contact the maintainers of that API and ask if they have any other supported methods of submitting data.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call webservice call direct using in form.

you need to form input SOAP request to call.

PHP Soap doc reference: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php
Sample: https://developer.decibel.net/sample-code-soap-php
[How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

Comment: can u gv a small example,

Comment: php language, and a linux web server