# Invoking API with SOAP using SoapClient - can't find method

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to connect to an API that uses SOAP. It is working for me with php/curl, but what I'd really like to do is use SoapClient, which looks like it would produce much cleaner code.

This is the php that works:

```
$xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
/" xmlns:v300="http://V300">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v300:GetNote soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <Request xsi:type="get:Request" xmlns:get="http://getNote.note.V300">
            <Security xsi:type="req:Security" xmlns:req="http://request.base.V300">
               <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$soapPassword.'</Password>
               <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$soapUser.'</Username>
            </Security>
            <NoteID xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$soapNoteID.'</NoteID>
         </Request>
      </v300:GetNote>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
                        "Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8",
                        "Accept: text/xml",
                        "SOAPAction: https://webservices.aus.vin65.com/V300/NoteService.cfc?wsdl", 
                        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                    ); 

$url = $soapUrl;


$ch = curl_init();
echo("set curl\n");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
echo("about to execute\n");
// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
echo('Got '.strlen($response)." characters in response\n");
curl_close($ch);

echo("Response:\n".$response."\n");
```

And this is my attempt at a SoapClient version, informed by this helpful StackExchange user over here: [How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

```
class Security{
        function Security($Username,$Password){
                $this->Username = $Username;
                $this->Password=$Password;
        }
}

class Request{
        function Request($Security,$NoteID){
                $this->Security = $Security;
                $this->NoteID = $NoteID;
        }
}

$client = new SoapClient($soapUrl);

$security = new Security($soapUser,$soapPassword);
$securityArray = array("Username"=>$soapUser,"Password"=>$soapPassword);

//$request = new Request($security,$soapNoteID);//gave error message "expects parameter 2 to be array"
//$request = array("Security"=>$security,"NoteID"=>$soapNoteID);//gave error message "No such operation 'GetNote'"        
$request = array("Security"=>$securityArray,"NoteID"=>$soapNoteID);//gave error message "No such operation 'GetNote'"

echo("Showing Request:\n");
var_dump($request);

$response=null;
try{
        $response = $client->__soapCall("GetNote",$request);
}catch(Exception $ex){
        echo("Caught Exception: ".$ex->getMessage()."\n");
        echo("Last Request was: ".$client->__getLastRequest()."\n");
        echo("Last Request Headers: ".$client->__getLastRequestHeaders()."\n");
        echo("Last Response was: ".$client->__getLastResponse()."\n");
        echo("Last Response Headers: ".$client->__getLastResponseHeaders()."\n");
}
if($response){
        var_dump($response);
}
```

As you can see, I've tried a couple of different ways to feed it the user/password/NoteID information, noting down which error message it gives me each time. Currently it's claiming that there's 'no such operation GetNote' - definintely not right, but I don't know what the underlying problem is.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i do $client->__getFunctions(), the method GetNote method shows up and works

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://webservices.aus.vin65.com/V300/NoteService.cfc?wsdl');

/**
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
Array
(
    [0] => Response SearchNotes(Request $Request)
    [1] => Response AddUpdateNote(Request $Request)
    [2] => Response GetNote(Request $Request)
)
*/
$result = $client->GetNote([
    'Security' => [
        'Password' => 'XXX',
        'Username' => 'XXX'
    ],
    'NoteID' => 'XXX'
]);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise you were allowed to invoke it directly, since the example code I copied off used __soapCall.

Comment: Anyway, yes, changing __soapCall to a direct use of the function worked perfectly, thanks very much