# SOAP working with xml via soapui but not with PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am creating an SOAP client using PHP and having issues with consuming. When I test the request direct XML using soapui it responds fine and works but with PHP using SoapClient class it tells me the same credentials which I use in soapui are incorrect.

Not sure what I am missing here. My code below
Below is my XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pric="http://upshot.co.uk/pricing_request_ws">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<pric:retrieveProductsPricing>
<username>apiuser</username>
<password>pword</password>
<postcode>EC2R 7HP</postcode>
</pric:retrieveProductsPricing>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is my PHP

```
$wsdl   = "http://URL?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

try
{
$options = array(
'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
'exceptions'=>true,
'trace'=>1,
'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);
$params = array(
    'User name' => 'apiuser',
    'Password' => 'pword',
    'Postcode' => 'EC2R 7HP'

);
$response = $client->retrieveProductsPricing($params);
print_r($response);
}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
print_r($e);
```

This is my first time configuring a soap client so I'm sure I have potentially made a mistake in this.

Comment: is `User name` meant to be `User name` or `Username`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the first code:

```
<username>apiuser</username>
<password>pword</password>
<postcode>EC2R 7HP</postcode>
```

You should use the same keys for the array

```
$params = array(
    'username' => 'apiuser',
    'password' => 'pword',
    'postcode' => 'EC2R 7HP'
);
```

[Useful examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

Comment: Ahh of course, lack of concentration! Thanks for that!