# Sending and requesting SOAP

Tags: php, soap, request, send

I'm trying to use an example that I found on the internet to send and receive from xml to a SOAP url, but I could not understand very well how SOAP works.

Can anyone help me? Here is the code that I'm passing:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:cad="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cadsus/v5r0/cadsusservice" xmlns:cnes="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v5r0/cnesusuario" xmlns:fil="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v5r0/filtropesquisa" xmlns:nom="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/pessoafisica/v1r2/nomecompleto" xmlns:nom1="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/pessoafisica/v1r0/nomefamilia" xmlns:cpf="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/documento/v1r2/cpf" xmlns:mun="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/v1r2/municipio" xmlns:uf="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/v1r1/uf" xmlns:tip="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/documento/v5r0/tipodocumento"><soap:Header><wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F6C95C679D248B6E3F143032021465917"><wsse:Username>CADSUS.CNS.PDQ.PUBLICO</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">kUXNmiiii#RDdlOELdoe00966</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">KkB/ki6qUjcZpGNqL4monw==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2015-04-29T15:10:14.659Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body><cad:requestPesquisar><cnes:CNESUsuario><cnes:CNES>6963447</cnes:CNES><cnes:Usuario>LEONARDO</cnes:Usuario><!--Optional:--><cnes:Senha>?</cnes:Senha></cnes:CNESUsuario><fil:FiltroPesquisa><fil:CPF><cpf:numeroCPF>66105234368</cpf:numeroCPF></fil:CPF><fil:tipoPesquisa>IDENTICA</fil:tipoPesquisa></fil:FiltroPesquisa><cad:higienizar>0</cad:higienizar></cad:requestPesquisar></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
XML;

$wsdl = 'https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'cache_ttl'     => 86400, 
    'login'=> "CADSUS.CNS.PDQ.PUBLICO",
    'password'=> "kUXNmiiii#RDdlOELdoe00966",
    'trace'         => true,
    'exceptions'    => true,
));

$xmlVar = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);
$client->getCustomerInfo($xml);
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getCustomerInfo") is not a valid method for this service in /home/itconect/www/sisam/testeJ.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/itconect/www/sisam/testeJ.php(18): SoapClient->__call('getCustomerInfo', Array) #1 /home/itconect/www/sisam/testeJ.php(18): SoapClient->getCustomerInfo('

I have another doubt in this code.  Would I receive the result or do I have to supplement it with something yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the WSDL of your code, than this SOAP service does not have a method called "getCustomerInfo". The methods according to the WSDL are pesquisar, consultar, incluir, atualizar, alterarSituacao and calcularGrauDeQualidade.

I'd also recommend using the php helpers instead of writing xml yourself (Examples: [How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)).

Edit: A very basic example

```
<?php

$wsdl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/BibleWebservice.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'         => true,
    'exceptions'    => true,
 ));

$keyword = new StdClass();
$keyword->BibleWords = "god";

$result = $client->GetBibleWordsbyKeyWord($keyword);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: so this XML already comes from the client mounted, and what I want is really what you said, pass this XML so that it returns the result to me in another XML, would you know how to help me in this case?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve exactly. For learning purposes I suggest you try some tutorials and use some public available services. I added a basic example to my answer, with which WSDL you can experiment.

Comment: @Felix You don't need to be working with XML. You pass the client a PHP object and it returns you a PHP object. You can pass the `classmap` option to the client so it can map the responses from XML to PHP.
Unless you want to work with XML for some reason.