# soap example successful request response using php curl for Income tax Return efiling(india)

Tags: php, curl, soap, request, wsdl

I have been trying this for many days but not succeeded. How to make a successful WSDL Soap request to ITR web site.
The sample soap url: https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingSecWS/ditsecws/BulkItrService?wsdl

and

The manual which I have refered is: https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/StaticPDF/Secure_WebServices_UserManual.pdf

If any one has any idea please let me know the Steps/Tutorial to successfully make a soap call using PHP apache2 Server, thank you in advance.

You can get a sample code here ..i am trying this.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(1);


//var_dump($xml); 
include('includexml.php');echo '<pre>';

 $soapUrl = "https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingSecWS/ditsecws/BulkItrService?wsdl";


//Create the client object
$soapclient = new SoapClient("$soapUrl",array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1));

try {
        print($soapclient->uploadBulkItr($includexml));
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception;
}

$res=$soapclient->__getFunctions();
print_r($res);
die;
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class ?

Comment: i have visted that link and also tried its working but not getting proper response from ITR webservices

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: i am just trying to make random call using that api in php curl using soap client with sample xml ,but not getting response in xml

Comment: What's in `$includexml`? You should be sending and object or array as the request, not a string of XML.