# Read json in web service asmx

Tags: c#, php, web-services

**I create web service in c# to receive json and insert it to data base :**

```
public string SaveData(string resultData)
{

DLR service = new DLR();

string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Error.txt");

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Json is sent :" + resultData +
       "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
}

RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resultData,settings);
    foreach (JsonData item in obj.results)
    {
        {
            var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[insert_RDL]", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msgId", item.msgId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to_mobile", item.to);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", item.status);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ttest", "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newtest", "");
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                //                    
            }
        }
    }
    return "OK ";
}
```

---

When i post the json by ajax in aspx page the page is sending json without problem . and i see json in error.txt .

**when i post the json by php :**

```
<?php
$data = '{"results": [{"msgId": "4000","to": "9665312114","status": "D"}, 
{"msgId": "859911880","to": "966535112578","status": "N"}, 
{"msgId":"859911880","to": "966535112579","status": "S"}]}' ;
$phpObj =  json_decode($data);
print_r($phpObj);
$resultData =  json_encode($phpObj);
print_r($resultData);
$client = new SoapClient("http://asdm.sa/DLR.asmx?wsdl");
$response = $client->SaveData($data);
print_r($response);
?>

----------
```

**The json is sending is NULL.
why the page not sending the json.**

when i open the error.txt :

> Json is sent :{"results": [{"msgId": "001","to": "9665312114","status": "D"}, {"msgId": "859911880","to": "966535112578","status": "N"}, {"msgId": "859911880","to": "966535112579","status": "S"}]}
> Date :2/3/2018 6:59:02 PM

---

> Json is sent :
>
> Date :2/3/2018 7:31:35 PM

Comment: looking at the contents of `error.txt` on your server suggests that at some points you have been sending json data ok

Comment: I have seen it no data

Comment: Doesn't SoapClient send XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem is in sent parameter. Please try next code

```
<?php
$data = '{"results": [{"msgId": "4000","to": "9665312114","status": "D"}, 
{"msgId": "859911880","to": "966535112578","status": "N"}, 
{"msgId":"859911880","to": "966535112579","status": "S"}]}' ;
$phpObj =  json_decode($data);
print_r($phpObj);
$resultData =  json_encode($phpObj);
print_r($resultData);
$client = new SoapClient("http://asdm.sa/DLR.asmx?wsdl");
$param = array('resultData' => $data);
$response = $client->SaveData($param);
print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandr
I add [FromBody] But same problem the json is sent is NULL

Comment: Can you check request in browser(network) or in backend Request object?

Comment: also can you try to change $resultData =  json_encode($phpObj); with $resultData.resultData =  json_encode($phpObj); and remove [FromBody]

Comment: Give error :
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\asdm.sa\httpdocs\sent.php on line 11

Comment: can you please try - $param = array('resultData' => $data);
$response = $client->SaveData($param);

Comment: Wheb add $param = array('resultData' => $data); $response = $client->SaveData($param)

The response is :
Json is sent :  System.Xml.XmlNode[]

Comment: please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class