# posting data from magento to a SOAP API

Tags: php, xml, web-services, magento, soap

I have an observer event that is capturing customer details anytime they are updated. At this point it posts that information to a var log.
I would like to get it to post to a SOAP API url.
[SOAP API URL](http://pop.dprocloud.com/DPAPIServices/DPAPIServices.asmx)
at this point I am trying to be pointed in the right direction of how to do this, I believe I need to write the information into an XML that matches the API.
I only have 6 fields that need to be filled so I don't think it will be to hard.

```
$fon = $billingaddress->getTelephone();
$street1 = $billingaddress->getStreet(1);
$street2 = $billingaddress->getStreet(2);
$city = $billingaddress->getCity();
$region = $billingaddress->getRegion();
$postcode = $billingaddress->getPostcode();
```

The phone number doubles as the customer #

Can somebody help me with the code to write the XML?

Answer (score 0):

This chunk will go inside your body tag, as shown in the examples [HERE](http://pop.dprocloud.com/DPAPIServices/DPAPIServices.asmx?op=UpdateCustomer).  For the XML, it is pretty straightforward, and you can do it as one `$request` variable instead of assigning several:

```
<?php
$request =  '<UpdateCustomer xmlns="http://www.dpro.com/DPAPIServices">'.
              '<aRequest>'.
//                  '<Username>'..'</Username>'.
//                  '<Password>'..'</Password>'.
                '<CustomerNumber>'.$billingaddress->getTelephone();.'</CustomerNumber>'.
                '<CustomerName>'.$billingAddress->getFirstname().' '.$billingAddress->getLastname().'</CustomerName>'.
                '<CustomerAddress1>'.$billingaddress->getStreet(1).'</CustomerAddress1>'.
                '<CustomerAddress2>'.$billingaddress->getStreet(2).'</CustomerAddress2>'.
                '<CustomerCity>'.$billingaddress->getCity().'</CustomerCity>'.
                '<CustomerState>'.$billingaddress->getRegion().'</CustomerState>'.
                '<CustomerZip>'.$billingaddress->getPostcode().'</CustomerZip>'.
              '</aRequest>'.
            '</UpdateCustomer>';
?>
```

**NOTE:**
I commented out the `Username` and `Password` because they weren't included in your example, and I am unsure whether they are your API user's credentials or related to the Customer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to write any XML when working with a SOAP API that already exists. Use the built-in `SoapClient`.

Have a look at the answers to this question if you need help with that: [How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)