# Passing array object in SOAP call using PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Given the below SOAP function (login) and types, how can I send (i need syntax) a SOAP request using php? I'm using WSDL file.

Function:

```
Array ( [0] => LoginResult login(LoginCallParms $loginCallParms)
```

Types:

```
[32]=> string(197) "struct LoginParms { string adminId; string password; ListOf_xsd_string response; ListOf_NameValue parms; string delegateId; ListOf_Base64Binary clientCert; DelegationAuthType delegateAuth; }"

[33]=> string(44) "struct LoginCallParms { LoginParms parms; }"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class