# SOAP request returning "XML Message String but class is class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl"

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I know very few things about XML and SOAP requests, but I am in a situation I have to consume a web service using PHP to send and receive data for my app, so any help would be appreciated.

The web service is a WSDL service, it exposes a function called `processIncomingMessage()` and expects the SOAP envelope body to look like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <processIncomingMessageRequest xmlns="http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws">
            <!-- Optional -->
            <messageRequest xmlns="">
                <DigitallySignedMessage>
                    <xmlMessage>[anyType]</xmlMessage>
                </DigitallySignedMessage>
            </messageRequest>
        </processIncomingMessageRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

So when I get the form values in JSON, I proceed like this:

```
//convert JSON to array
$data =  json_decode($json, true);

//convert array to XML
$xmlMessage = ArrayToXml::convert($data, $root);

//set the function arguments
$messageRequest = [
    "messageRequest" => [
        "DigitallySignedMessage" => [
            "xmlMessage" => $xmlMessage,
            "isXmlString" => $isXmlString,
            "messageType" => $messageType
        ],
        "traderID" => $traderID,
        "wsPass" => $wsPass,
        "wsUserID" => $wsUserID
    ]
];

//create soap client instance
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soapOptions);

//call the SOAP function and save the response in a var
$response = $client->processIncomingMessage($messageRequest);
```

The `ArrayToXml` makes use of the `DOMDocument` class to create the xml and 
I fount it here: https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml/blob/master/src/ArrayToXml.php

Now, even though I validated the XML created above against the provided xsd file and on the web service's website with their own tool, the SOAP response looks like this:

```
status: Invalid Argument
explanation: XML Message String but class is class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here... 
Could anybody shed some light?

Comment: Offhand it sounds like the function expects a string as the messageRequest parameter but is getting an object of some kind instead.

Comment: When I call the lastRequest I get this, 
 ````<xmlMessage>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;CC515A&gt;&lt;SynIdeMES1&gt;UNOC&lt;/SynIdeMES1&gt;&lt;SynVerNumMES2&gt;3&lt;/SynVerNumMES2&gt;&lt;MesSenMES3&gt;TRADER&lt;/MesSenMES3&gt;&lt;MesRecMES6&gt;NICA&lt;/MesRecMES6&gt;&lt;DatOfPreMES9&gt;101103&lt;/DatOfPreMES9&gt;&lt;TimOfPreMES10&gt;...````
so I am assuming I send a string. Right?

Comment: Seems like $xmlMessage  would be a string, but the code is passing $messageRequest to that function which seems to be an array

Comment: The $xmlMessage is the actual message I need to send... it is my form values converted to xml

Comment: Got it, but you then put that into $messageRequest, and t that is what gets passed to  processIncomingMessage. If the function expects XML, its not getting it

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs for `processIncomingMessage`?

Comment: https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicisnet/MessageProcessorService?wsdl

this is it...

Comment: Hmm, was hoping for more to go on than the wsdl. What service are you trying to use exactly?

Comment: It's a customs declaration web service...

Comment: Hmm, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714489/1376624

Comment: This WS gives me the option to pass the xmlMessage as an embedded XML structure instead of a string. Is there any chance that you know how I could accomplish that...?

Comment: No I dont, sorry

Comment: That's ok! Thank you for taking the time to help me out...