# integrate php project with WSDL file

Tags: php, wcf, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a WSDL file - not url ending by '?wsdl', and I should integrate with it using basic auth - username and password, my friend did it in c#, by adding the file as service refference in visual studio, how can I make it using a php project?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function of `WebService`, mainly `soap` and `WSDL`. Take a look at this: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)